# How to use shell variables in su command string?

Tags: bash, sh, su

In Shell script i am trying to pass an array to a Sudo SU command as shown below

```
VAR=(1,2,3)
sudo su $USER -c "for p in ${VAR[@]} ; do echo $p ; done;"
```

Issue is `$p` value is not getting printed. I have tried all the below possible way but not able to print `$p` value

```
sudo su $USER -c "for p in "${VAR[@]}" ; do echo "$p" ; done;"
sudo su $USER -c 'for p in ${VAR[@]} ; do echo $p ; done;'
```

**Sample Output of the command**

```
+ sudo su USER -c 'for p in 1 2 3 4 5 ; do echo  ; done;'
+ echo "Script Ended"
```

Comment: You need to get your quoting right, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Answer (score 5):

You could use `sh` as an argument to `sudo su`, to pass the variable, then, inside the `-c` call, you can access the var as you would do in a regular function call (`$@ $1 ...`);

```sh
sudo su $USER -c 'for p in "${@}"; do echo ${p}; done;' sh "${arr[@]}"
```

```
so@deb:~$ arr=(1 2 3)
so@deb:~$ sudo su $USER -c 'for p in "${@}"; do echo ${p}; done;' sh "${arr[@]}"
1
2
3
so@deb:~$
```

Comment: Hi and thank you, it's working for bash and su as root.
su $USER -c 'for p in "${@}"; do echo ${p}; done;' bash "${arr[@]}"